# Need help on bootstrap responsive design for laptop tablet phone

Tags: html

My bootstrap styles are not working on laptops/tablets. I inspected the code and I did use `col-lg` `col-md` `col-sm` but when I inspect in the browser it's not working. There should be a small even space between each image around 15-20px.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <article class="container-fluid">
    <section style="margin-right:15px; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px;" class="row">
      <img src="dog1.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom:0;">
      <img src="dog2.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog3.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog4.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog5.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog6.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog7.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog8.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog9.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">
      <img src="dog10.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0; ">
      <img src="dog11.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0; ">
      <img src="dog12.jpg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0; ">
    </section>
  </article>
</body>
```

How can I make my code match the bootstrap design? On a big-screen laptop, it should be rows of 4, and on a small screen laptop it should be 3 rows, On a tablet, it should be 2 rows and on a phone, it should be 1 row. No custom CSS is allowed

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: You _really_ shouldn't be overriding row styles like that. Messing with the grid is a recipe for headaches. Put styling on column content instead.

Comment: What does "no CSS allowed" mean? You have a whole bunch right there, inline. If anything, you should use an embedded style element to clean things up.

Comment: Please tag Bootstrap, including your version.

Comment: With whatever I understood, you don't need any `padding` classes that you have applied here to the images. Just add a gutter class to your row, such as `g-3` (g-3 by default will be 16px on all sides). Refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/, and you'll be good to go. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/gvx548oe/1/